# How can I handle strings containing img tag and extract the source url?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a json like below.

I am using the text in the value for the `content` key in my application.

**1.** How can I remove the `img` tag from text?

**2.** How can I get the `img src url` from this tag?

Is there a function, framework, tool for split text, regex or filter?

```
        "entries": [
            {
                "title": "İstanbul Boğazı'ndan böyle geçti!",
                "link": "http://www.posta.com.tr/turkiye/HaberDetay/Istanbul-Bogazi-ndan-boyle-gecti-.htm?ArticleID=349553",
                "author": "",
                "publishedDate": "Tue, 21 Jun 2016 22:42:00 -0700",
                "contentSnippet": "Rusya donanmasına ait 156 bordo numaralı 'Yamal' adlı savaş gemisi İstanbul Boğazı'ndan geçerek Marmara Denizi'ne açıldı ...",
                "content": "<img src=\"http://icdn.posta.com.tr/editor/HD/22/6/2016/fft2mm7873698.jpg\" alt=\"İstanbul Boğazı&#39;ndan böyle geçti!\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding:2px 10px\">Rusya donanmasına ait 156 bordo numaralı 'Yamal' adlı savaş gemisi İstanbul Boğazı'ndan geçerek Marmara Denizi'ne açıldı<p> </p>\n\tKaradeniz'den İstanbul Boğazı'na giriş yapan savaş gemisi saat 06.00 sıralarında Boğaz'dan geçti. Marmara Denizine doğru ilerleyen savaş gemisine Sahil Güvenlik Komutanlığı ekipleri botlarla eşlik etti. Geminin güvertesinde silahlı askerlerin nöbet tutması dikkat çekti.\n\n\tOzan URAL / İSTANBUL (DHA)",
                "categories": []
            },
            {
                "title": "Ağaç tepesinden Nihat Hatipoğlu'nu izlediler!",
                "link": "http://www.posta.com.tr/turkiye/HaberDetay/Agac-tepesinden-Nihat-Hatipoglu-nu-izlediler-.htm?ArticleID=349552",
                "author": "",
                "publishedDate": "Tue, 21 Jun 2016 22:35:00 -0700",
                "contentSnippet": "Prof. Dr. Nihat Hatipoğlu ile ekrana gelen iftar ve sahur Özel programları binlerce insanı Sultanahmet'e çekiyor \n\tNihat ...",
                "content": "<img src=\"http://icdn.posta.com.tr/editor/HD/22/6/2016/fft2mm7873685.jpg\" alt=\"Ağaç tepesinden Nihat Hatipoğlu&#39;nu izlediler!\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding:2px 10px\">Prof. Dr. Nihat Hatipoğlu ile ekrana gelen iftar ve sahur Özel programları binlerce insanı Sultanahmet'e çekiyor<p> </p>\n\tNihat Hatipoğlu'nun sunumuyla ekrana gelen iftar ve sahur programları için kurulan özel alana, saat 15:00'ten sonra izleyiciler akın etmeye başlıyor. Yoğun ilgi nedeniyle alan adeta dolup taşıyor.\n\n\tSabah'ın haberine göre önceki gün oturacak yer bulamayanlar, programı çevredeki ağaçlara tırmanarak takip etti.",
                "categories": []
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cheeio for this.

`npm install cheerio --save`

```
$ = cheerio.load(entry.content);
```

To get Image URL

```
var imgUrl = $('img').attr('src')
```

To remove Image

```
$('img').remove()
```

To get back html

```
var html = $.html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You find many solutions out the by just google the same with about javascript in case. U can take most of classic Javascript functions and use them to edit your strings. For your case the following should work.

```js
var yourEntries = "<img src=\"http://icdn.posta.com.tr/editor/HD/22/6/2016/fft2mm7873698.jpg\" alt=\"İstanbul Boğazı&#39;ndan böyle geçti!\" align=\"left\" style=\"padding:2px 10px\">Rusya donanmasına ait 156 bordo numaralı 'Yamal' adlı savaş gemisi İstanbul Boğazı'ndan geçerek Marmara Denizi'ne açıldı<p> </p>\n\tKaradeniz'den İstanbul Boğazı'na giriş yapan savaş gemisi saat 06.00 sıralarında Boğaz'dan geçti. Marmara Denizine doğru ilerleyen savaş gemisine Sahil Güvenlik Komutanlığı ekipleri botlarla eşlik etti. Geminin güvertesinde silahlı askerlerin nöbet tutması dikkat çekti.\n\n\tOzan URAL / İSTANBUL (DHA)"

var yourResult;

//Dont use this for case if everything is always the same and the "IMG" is just at the first 4 positions -> I just made this if the img is later in the string coming
for (var i = 0; i < yourEntries.length; i++){
  
  if (yourEntries[i] === "i" || yourEntries[i+1] === "m" ||   yourEntries [i+2] === "g" || yourEntries [i+3] === ""){
     
    var yourStart = i + 4;
    var yourEnd = yourEntries.length;
    
    yourResult = yourEntries.substring(yourStart, yourEnd)
  }
}
```

There are many options how to solve your problem. This one should give u a view how to do it without some plugins. You also can use the .match function to compare 2 strings with each other -> yourCompareString.match("img") -> results true

Hope i could help you

*//Little hint try yourself the same for the src= problem -> U can search for the 2 \*

Answer (score -1):

If this is format for content values, you can extract substring and get your url.

```
String requiredString = contentString.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, contentString.indexOf("alt="));
```

The method's signature for substring is:

```
str.substring(int start, int end); // start is the start index and end is the end index
```

Comment: Are we talking about react native?